# What does the abbreviation 'compl.' mean in the Oxford English Dictionary (OED)

Tags: grammar, abbreviations, dictionaries

*Note: One might (understandably) think my question [off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because the OED *should* list the abbreviations it uses, and if not, surely Google will have the answer. Please bear with me while I explain.*

I wanted to learn more about the word, *bespeak*, so I turned to the venerable Oxford English Dictionary (OED).<sup>1</sup> Definition number 7 for *bespeak* reads in part:<sup>2</sup>

> **7.**
>
> a. To speak of, tell of, be the outward expression of; to indicate, give evidence of.
>
> 1629   J. Earle *Micro-cosmogr.* (ed. 5) xx. sig. E2v   His very
>   countenance and gesture bespeak how much he is.
>
> 1814   Wordsworth *Excursion* i. 42   But her House Bespake a sleepy
>   hand of negligence.    1863   C. C. Clarke *Shakespeare-characters*
>   iii. 65   Hamlet's proneness to soliloquy bespeaks the reflective man.
>
> **b.** with *compl.*
>
> a1704   T. Brown *Oration in Praise Drunkenness* in *Wks.* (1707) I.
>   i. 47   Such whose smiling Aspect bespeaks them Friends.
>
> 1815   *Scribbleomania* 18   Symptoms bespeaking me rash.

**QUESTION:** What does '*compl.*' mean in definition 7b?

---

#### My Research

- I looked for a list of abbreviations in the OED itself, but if it's there, I could not find it.
- I Googled "compl." (with and without the quotation marks);
- I Googled ("compl." AND abbreviation) - with and without the parentheses;
- I searched several abbreviation sites; and
- I reviewed publishing terms and their abbreviations in the BlueBook (citation guide for law reviews and other legal writing).

#### What I learned

- In the publishing world, '*comp.*' stands for *compilation* or *compile*.<sup>3</sup>
- In the legal world, '*compl.*' [stands for *complaint*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compl.).
- [AcronymFinder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/COMPL.html) indicates that '*compl*' stands for *complete* or *completion*.
- AllAcronyms.com informed me that '*comp.*' can refer to [compound](https://www.allacronyms.com/compound/abbreviated) or [composition](https://www.allacronyms.com/_medical/Comp/Composition).
- [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/compl) instructed me that '*compl*' refers to a 1966 article in The Computer Journal, titled "The COMPL Language and Operating System". 4

Unfortunately, I did not learn what the OED means by 'compl.'

~ Mark

---

#### Footnotes

1. [Subscription required](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/oxford-english-dictionary-online-9780198605553). However, most university and public libraries provide their members with [access to OED Online](http://public.oed.com/how-to-subscribe/does-my-library-subscribe/). There are also the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://oxforddictionaries.com/), abbreviated ODO (Oxford Dictionary Online). The URL for *Oxford Dictionary - English* is https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/
2. 'in part' - I did not include all the examples of historical usage (quotations) because the OED (print or online) is protected by copyright, therefore I did not want to copy and paste the entire definition verbatim.
3. *The Bluebook: A Uniform System of Citation* 517 tbl.T.14 (Columbia Law Review Ass’n et al. eds., 20th ed. 2015).
4. A. G. Fraser, J. D. Smart; The COMPL Language and Operating System. *Comput J* 1966; 9 (2): 144-156. [doi:10.1093/comjnl/9.2.144](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/9/2/144/623346/The-COMPL-Language-and-Operating-System#)

Comment: There's a list of abbreviations on home page, with _compl.  complement_,
_Compl.  complete_.

Comment: Excellent! Good to know that.

Comment: P.S. I am using the Stack Exchange iPhone app, which does not show the abbreviations list. I will suggest adding it for future iOS app versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question because I finally found it!

Google came to the rescue when it located [The Oxford English Dictionary: List of Abbreviations](http://www.indiana.edu/~letrs/help-services/QuickGuides/oed-abbr.html#c) on the Indiana University website--posted 21 years ago!

I eventually also found the [OED abbreviation list](http://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/abbreviations/#c) on the OED website. (Their site would benefit from some user testing...).

#### The Answer

In the OED, 'compl.' stands for *complement*.

---

#### What does *complement* mean in this context?

Here is the relevant [definition of complement](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/37642) from the OED:

> b. Grammar. One or more words joined to another to complete the sense
>   (see quots.).
>
> 1876   C. P. Mason *Eng. Gram.* (ed. 21) §391   Many verbs do not make
>   complete sense by themselves..and the words used with them to make
>   predication complete may be called the complement of the predicate.
>
> 1964   E. Palmer tr. A. Martinet *Elements Gen. Linguistics* iv. 11
>   Hier, il y avait fête au village...hier and au village..may be
>   eliminated without the utterance ceasing to be a normal sentence..and
>   this is what is meant by the traditional terminology which speaks of
>   them as ‘complements’.

#### In-depth discussion about complements (grammar)

TheFreeDictionary.com offers the following definition, along with an [extensive discussion of the different types of complements](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Complements.htm) (in the grammatical sense).

> Complements are words or groups of words that are necessary to
>   complete the meaning of another part of the sentence. Complements act
>   like modifiers to add additional meaning to the word or words they are
>   attached to. However, unlike adjunct modifiers, they do not add
>   supplemental information—they provide information that is necessary to
>   achieve the intended meaning in the sentence.

---

#### If English is your second language...

Note that *complement* and *compliment* are sometimes confused. They are two different words, with different meanings.