# What is the meaning of 'compl.' in 'compl. steel'

Tags: abbreviations, technical

I've encountered the term 'compl. steel' in a document (related to mechanical engineering). Simple googling of the term shows many pages related to mechanical engineering and metalworks, but it doesn't seem any of them expand the word 'compl.'.

The search relates this term with 'complex phase', as can be seen [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.worldautosteel.org/steel-basics/steel-types/complex-phase-cp-steels/&ved=2ahUKEwi3uODzm9nqAhWtILcAHWE5BRwQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw08XylKWLeNkbvHWweOJ430) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://automotive.arcelormittal.com/products/flat/first_gen_AHSS/CP&ved=2ahUKEwi3uODzm9nqAhWtILcAHWE5BRwQFjABegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw3aXBrx9F8hwdm5i9IWP_w_). But I don't think this is correct.

I know one thread in this forum that talks about ['compl.' as 'complement'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/402333/what-does-the-abbreviation-compl-mean-in-the-oxford-english-dictionary-oed) but I cannot be fully sure if this is the correct meaning.

Comment: Please include the term you've encountered in the context in which it was encountered (i.e., include the whole sentence that uses "compl. steel" that you encountered).

Comment: The 'document' in question is actually a list of words without any sentences. I would like to provide more context but unfortunately there isn't any.

Comment: It as an abbreviation of **complete** as in "complete assembly". For example an item in a parts or stock list might be "widget complete steel" or "spraddle complete rubber" and so on. Here is another [example](https://www.lastentarvike.fi/verkkokauppa/prams-and-strollers/buggies-&-strollers/bugaboo-ant-style-set-compl-steel-blue.html) which says "Bugaboo Ant Style Set Compl, Steel Blue" although 'steel' here refers to its colour.

Comment: Likely to be either jargon or an abbreviation made up on the spot. A procurement site might be able to help. It's not really a problem in English Usage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EL&U.

Answer (score 2):

The uses of "compl. steel" I can find are all for replacement parts and/or parts ordering. In these cases, the two are just separate adjectives describing the part: compl. for "complex" meaning it is not a single part but a set (complex) of parts that are sold together as a unit. And steel to describe the material in the usual sense.

e.g.: on this [list of parts](https://www.gabelstapler-rehberg.de/media/catalog/1513-1526.pdf)

> Single wheel compl. nylon
> Single wheel compl. steel

Finding "complex" in a parts list and not abbreviated is rarer, but some parts lists do it.

e.g.: on this [part order page](https://www.fancyscooters.com/item01583-scooter-part-FH150ccATV-rear-wheel-complex.html)

> Rear Wheel Complex for FH150ccATV

Comment: Meaning to say that 'Single wheel' belongs to a set of parts, or 'Single wheel' is itself composed of many parts?

Comment: See the list in that linked pdf: The part in question is a "single wheel complex", in one case, the complex is made of nylon, in the other it is made of steel. See also other occurrences of "compl." on that list.

Comment: Indeed. Having searched for **"compl steel"** in Google Books I noticed several hits where that text was preceded by the word **deck**, so I repeated my quoted string search with **"deck compl steel"**. That version got me half-a dozen hits, with Google Books helpfully suggesting *Did you mean "deck **complete** steel"?* When I clicked "Yes", I got many more hits contextually similar to the first ones.